# Placing dots along the interior points of a path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a path with black dots being placed along the interior vertices of the path.
The black dots should all have the same (but customizable) width.

I can create this, but using  the somewhat verbose code below by using the `circle` command after each interior vertex point.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) --  (2,3)  circle[radius=0.05] --  (-0.5,2) circle[radius=0.05]  -- (0,1); 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

giving me this:

[image]

How do I shorten this code, so that I can avoid writing `circle` everytime to be able to place dots along the path? Notice that currently, the circles are filled in with white, I would like them to be filled with `black` but using the `fill=black` option on the circle does not seem to work.

EDIT:

Also how do I modify the `|-` and `-|` commands to do the same thing as above for rectilinear paths?

Comment: You could do `\tikzset{c/.style={insert path={node[inner sep=0pt, minimum size=1mm, circle, fill, #1]{}}}}` and use `[c]` instead of `circle[…]`. This allows the circles to have a different appearance as the path itself. For `|-` and `-|` you'd use an additional `[c=midway]` to add the circle at the bend.